# Python: iterate over a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

given the following `dictionary`:

```
playlists={'user':[
               {'playlist1':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'Karma Police','artist': 'Radiohead', 'count': "1.0"},
                    {'name': 'Bitter Sweet Symphony','artist': 'The Verve','count': "2.0"}                    
                     ]
                    }
               },
               {'playlist2':{
                    'tracks': [        
                    {'name': 'We Will Rock You','artist': 'Queen', 'count': "3.0"},
                    {'name': 'Roxanne','artist': 'Police','count': "5.0"}                    
                     ]
                  }
                },
              ]
            }
```

though not very elegantly, I can fetch keys and values in such a structure:

`keys`:

```
userX = [user[0] for user in playlists.iteritems()][0] //userX
playlist1 = list(playlists['userX'][0].keys())[0] //playlist1
```

and nested `values`:

```
artist = playlists['user'][0]["playlist1"]['tracks'][0]['artist'] //Radiohead
count = playlists['user'][1]["playlist2"]['tracks'][0]['count'] //3.0
```

but I'm a bit confused as to how access all `playlists names for playlists` and all `artists for tracks in playlists` using any `iteration` tool.

how can I do it?

Comment: You can also find `user` by `list(playlists.keys())[0]` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to access the playlist names and artist names:

```
# Define generator to return dicts under each user
lists = (x for user in playlists.itervalues() for x in user)
print [name for play_list in lists for name in play_list.iterkeys()]

lists = (x for user in playlists.itervalues() for x in user)
track_lists = (content['tracks'] for p in lists for content in p.itervalues())
print [track['artist'] for track_list in track_lists for track in track_list]
```

Output:

```
['playlist1', 'playlist2']
['Radiohead', 'The Verve', 'Queen', 'Police']
```

Note that above works only with Python 2, with Python 3 `values` & `keys` should be used instead of `itervalues` & `iterkeys`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to extract a flat list of all playlist names you can use a list comprehension. The mix of dictionaries and lists adds a little complexity.

```
all_playlists = [ playlist_title 
                  for user in playlists 
                  for user_playlists in playlists[user]
                  for playlist_title in user_playlists ]
print all_playlists

all_artists = [ track['artist']
                for user in playlists
                for user_playlists in playlists[user]
                for playlist_title in user_playlists 
                for track in user_playlists[playlist_title]['tracks'] ]
print all_artists
```

gives

```
['playlist1', 'playlist2']
['Radiohead', 'The Verve', 'Queen', 'Police']
```

Note that this will give combined lists of playlists/artists across all users in the playlists dict